# What is the sequence of migrating data from one Salesforce to another Salesforce org

Tags: data-loader, data, migration-tool, data-migration

I want to transfer all my data from one Salesfoce org to another Salesforce org.
Kindly let me know sequence of data import. What object's data shoud i import first?

Comment: What are objects you are migrating?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too broad.

You should import first parent records and then import the child records.

Like this sequence:

- User
- Account
- Contact
- Case
- Task
- Event

Also, rather than migrating all the data from one sandbox to other, you can think of refreshing a sandbox from the sandbox itself as long as sandbox types are same.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce gives Knowledge Article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384386&type=1

It seems to me that it is very clear

Description
When you load large amounts of data or migrate data, update your objects in the following order:

Resolution

1. Accounts
2. Contacts  (related to Accounts)
3. Opportunities  (related to Accounts and Contacts)
4. Products
5. Product Line Items  (related to Opportunities and Products)
6. Cases  (related to Contacts)
7. Leads
8. Campaigns
9. Campaign Members  (related to Campaigns, Contacts, and Leads)
10. Contracts  (related to Accounts and Contacts)
11. Assets  (related to Accounts, Contacts, Cases, and Products)

Custom Objects - The order for custom objects depends on your Salesforce implementation
Activities - Activities are the last object in the sequence and can be related to most standard and custom object.

Comment: You should reproduce the important parts of that link here so that when (not if, when) Salesforce decides to change their link structure or article Ids again, this answer can still be useful.

Comment: @DerekF you are right - reproduced

Comment: And upvoted. Thanks for taking the time to reproduce the contents of the link!

Answer (score -1):

Based on your dependencies and master-detail lookups.

Though generally you always start with Accounts, Contacts and Leads.

Move on to objects that have these as their main relationships, like Cases.

Then you select objects that are related to Cases only, like Case Comments.

You really should be familiar with your current SF org schema to decide the order, as it isn't something standard due to different setups people have.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384386&language=en_US&type=1 The order you have suggested has nothing to do with the relationship